# ReactJS form need to submit 2 times to work

Tags: reactjs

```
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [age, setAge] = useState("");
  const initialValues = {
    name: "",
    age: "",
  };
  const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState(initialValues);
  const [formErrors, setFormErrors] = useState({});
  const [isSubmit, setIsSubmit] = useState(false);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormValues({ ...formValues, [name]: value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    setFormErrors(validate(formValues));
    setIsSubmit(true);
  };

 const validate = (values) => {
    const errors = {};
    if (!values.name) {
      errors.name = "Name is required";
    }
    if (!values.age) {
      errors.age= "Age is required";
    }
    return errors;
  };

 const userCreate = async () => {
    await api.post("/createuser", {
      name,
      age,
    });
  };

 return (
    <div class="container">
      <Form
        onSubmit={
          Object.keys(formErrors).length === 0 && isSubmit
            ? userCreate
            : handleSubmit
        }
      >
        <Form.Field>
          <label>Name</label>
          <input
            name="name"
            onChange={(e) => {
              setName(e.target.value);
              handleChange(e);
            }}
            values={formValues.name}
          />
          <span className="error-message">{formErrors.name}</span>
        </Form.Field>
        <Form.Field>
          <label>Age</label>
          <input
            name="age"
            onChange={(e) => {
              setAge(e.target.value);
              handleChange(e);
            }}
            values={formValues.age}
          />
          <p className="error-message">{formErrors.age}</p>
        </Form.Field>
        <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
```

I'm trying to use **axios** to do POST method for creating user.

I got everything works fine but there's one small problem but I don't know how to fix.

The problem is that I always need to submit the form 2 times to make the POST request. There's nothing happen in the first submit, but it will work in the second submit.

Does anyone know what's wrong with my code?

**Edited**

According to @DBS solution.
I'm trying to follow the steps but now the form can't submit anymore. Can someone let me know if I missed something?

```
const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [age, setAge] = useState("");
  const initialValues = {
    name: "",
    age: "",
  };
  const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState(initialValues);
  const [formErrors, setFormErrors] = useState({});
  const [isSubmitting, setIsSubmitting] = useState(false);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormValues({ ...formValues, [name]: value });
  };




const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    if (!Object.keys(formErrors).length && !isSubmitting) {
      setFormErrors(validate(formValues));
    } else {
      userCreate();
      setisSubmitting(true);
    }
  };

 const validate = (values) => {
    const errors = {};
    if (!values.name) {
      errors.name = "Name is required";
    }
    if (!values.age) {
      errors.age= "Age is required";
    }
    return errors;
  };

 const userCreate = async () => {
    await api.post("/createuser", {
      name,
      age,
    });
  };

 return (
    <div class="container">
      <Form
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      >
        <Form.Field>
          <label>Name</label>
          <input
            name="name"
            onChange={(e) => {
              setName(e.target.value);
              handleChange(e);
            }}
            values={formValues.name}
          />
          <span className="error-message">{formErrors.name}</span>
        </Form.Field>
        <Form.Field>
          <label>Age</label>
          <input
            name="age"
            onChange={(e) => {
              setAge(e.target.value);
              handleChange(e);
            }}
            values={formValues.age}
          />
          <p className="error-message">{formErrors.age}</p>
        <
```

Comment: Where does `productCreate` come from? (Or is that supposed to be `userCreate`?)

Comment: Yea that's userCreate. Just a typo

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is your `isSubmit`, it is required to be `true` for `userCreate` to be called:

```
onSubmit={
  Object.keys(formErrors).length === 0 && isSubmit
    ? userCreate
    : handleSubmit
}
```

But it starts as `false`:

```
const [isSubmit, setIsSubmit] = useState(false);
```

And is only ever updated when `handleSubmit` is called (which, confusingly, is only called when the validation fails)

So your current code does this:

- `isSubmit` is `false`
- Submit is clicked, `handleSubmit` is called and `isSubmit` is set to `true`
- Submit is clicked again, now `isSubmit` is `true` it will call `userCreate`

To solve this, there are a few different approaches, but I would:

- Move all the submit handler logic into `onSubmit={handleSubmit}` (To keep things clear)
- Inside there, do your error length check (0 error) and `isSubmit` (Which I would probably rename to `isSubmitting` for clarity, and make sure it's false) (E.g. `!Object.keys(formErrors).length && !isSubmitting`)
- If there are errors, show the appropriate message (Leaving `isSubmitting` as `false`)
- If not, call `userCreate` (And set `isSubmitting` to `true`)
- Lastly, if this can be submitted multiple times, add an effect/callback/then to reset `isSubmitting` once the call is complete.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I'm following your step but the form can't submit anymore. I'm not sure if I did something wrong in the code. 1. change isSubmit => isSubmitting 2. I set onSubmit={handleSubmit} 3. const handleSubmit = (e) => { if (Object.keys(formErrors).length === 0 && isSubmitting) { userCreate(); setisSubmitting(true); } else { setFormErrors(validate(formValues)); } };

Comment: Did you missing something?

Comment: @Jacky You would need `&& !isSubmitting`, in your conditional. I'll clarify the answer.

Comment: the form now can't submit if I put all the correct data at the first time, it will works after the validation is check. I've also edited the code above. Can you take a look, please?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the `isSubmitting` flag for something? if not below might be work for you.

If there is no error, calling the create method

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  setFormErrors(validate(formValues));

  if(Object.keys(formErrors).length === 0) {
    userCreate();
  }
};
```

if `isSubmitting` is used to check the submit or create in progress

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  setFormErrors(validate(formValues));
    
  if(Object.keys(formErrors).length === 0) {
    setIsSubmitting(true);
    userCreate();
  }
};
```

The flag `isSubmitting` should be set as false on API is success or failed
`setIsSubmitting(false)`

Comment: Hey, Thank you for your answer. I tried your solution but there's one problem. If the first time I clicked submit without any data, then the error message will raise, then I enter all the data for the second time to submit, then I need to submit two times to make it work